# Selenium get table contents in Python3

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to pick up all the hrefs in a table using Selenium (Chrome Driver)

I have a table of items where each table row looks like.

```
<tr>
    <td>
      <a href="a html page reference" class="itemName">
         <img data-script="item_image" data-widget="item-image" data-item="i165187" 
              data-size="70x70"  class="img" 
              src="html://source of image" alt="">The item name</a>
    </td>
    <td class="hide-s">Kitchen</td>
    <td class="hide-s">
      <span class="flag UK"></span>
      <span class="itemCountry">UK</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have been playing around with various selenium methods with the essential problem (I think) being that there is no "name" associated with the href.

For example in the following I am hoping to get 'links' to contain the row so that I can pick out the hrefs.

```
links = []

links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('itemName')

for link in links:
    link_urls_list.append(link.text)
```

Comment: just added <tr> tags.

Comment: What output are you getting? Is it different from the expected output?

Comment: Yes, the code I am trying lands me with a load of web elements which do not contain the hrefs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to collect all the *hrefs* you can use the following solution:

```
link_urls_list = []
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr//td/a[@class='itemName']")
for link in links:
    link_urls_list.append(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: It worked straight away. Thanks very much. I need to work on my thin understanding of Xpaths.